# How I can find built-in modules directory's of node?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I want to find some built-in modules of node js directory's like URL,Fs or http!
Where is their root library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you won't be able to find it on your machine because they are most likely (for the sake of simplicity and performance) bundled inside of the Node executable.

However you can find the source code on the original Nodejs repo. All modules you are looking for are located [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib)